# Android Management API Disable Camera Except For Custom App

Tags: android, mdm, android-management-api

I am exploring about using Android Management API to restrict the use of Camera for my company device. So what I need is disable all camera access except for 1 application that my company made to take picture using camera.
So what I want to ask is it possible to restrict all camera access using android management api except for 1 application that my company made?

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds depending on the use case:

By setting the device to [fully manage mode](https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview#company-owned-devices-for-knowledge-workers), you can [disable camera](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#4.20.-disable-cameras_1) access on the entire device using the policy `"cameraDisabled": true`. In this case, there is no way you can allow exceptions for specific custom app since the policy is device-wide and cannot be overridden with  `"permissionGrants": [ {object ([PermissionGrant])} ]`.

With that being said there are a few things we can do depending on the use case:

- Making the camera app the default app that responds to `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent using [PersistentPreferredActivity](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#persistentpreferredactivity)
- Setting up the device in kiosk mode and expose the camera app to the user.